# how to use a vector and its `rev` to create 2 zips in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use a vector to create 2 different zips :

```rust
let foo = vec!['a','b','c'];
let bar = vec!['a','b','c'];
let it = foo.zip(bar);
let it_rev = foo.rev().zip(bar);
```

```
use of moved value: `foo`
```

because of my use of `zip`.

How to achieve what I want to do ?

Comment: Please build a [MRE] (with real code, not pseudocode) and explain what's the desired result

Comment: What are close_chars?

Comment: will ask another question

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter) on the vectors:

```rust
let close_chars = vec!['c', 'b', 'd'];
let my_vec: Vec<char> = vec!['a','b','c'];
let it = my_vec.iter().zip(close_chars.iter());
let it_rev = my_vec.iter().rev().zip(close_chars.iter());
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9cd0c4f6c76e82f99583337c4bcabcb4)

Comment: yes will ask another question with a playground example